# How do you re-unlock all story missions with a new character?

Tags: diablo-iii

I unlocked/beat the entire story. My hardcore character died. So I started a new one, got to level 70 (mix between power leveling and bounties). Now I went to Campaign to try to farm some of my gear back, and it's trying to make me redo the entire campaign again....

Is there anyway to get access to any campaign mission without having to redo it again..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. With each new character, you have to start the campaign fresh. The only way to get access to *any* campaign mission is to play through the entire campaign.

However, you can skip around if you have a friend who has all campaign missions available. If he starts a game, you can join him anywhere along the plotline, and as long as you finish a quest, that quest will still be available for you to choose when playing alone. In this way, you can at least unlock the starting points that would be interesting to you.

Comment: It is convenient to unlock the final step of boss quest of each Act. This way, you will get all the steps of that final quest (i.e. after getting the "Kill Malthael" quest step, you will be able to play entire Angel of Death quest from the start, allowing you to listen to ghost's conversations). Also, you will get the first quest in an act (confirmed for Act V only - anyway, just kill the previous boss and you're here).